# Dynamically add targets to a Prometheus configuration

Tags: prometheus

For a particular job in Prometheus, it seems like the typical config is something like this:

```
static_configs:
- targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

But in the case where I want a dynamic list of hosts, what would be the approach there? I was looking at `scrape_config` but that doesn't seem to accomplish what I'm after (unless I'm misreading?).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If one of the provided service discovery mechanisms doesn't already do what you need, you can use [file_sd_configs](https://www.robustperception.io/using-json-file-service-discovery-with-prometheus/) to provide targets on the fly.

Comment: There's a nice blog from RobustPerception on this topic [Using JSON file service discovery with Prometheus](https://www.robustperception.io/using-json-file-service-discovery-with-prometheus) (a YAML is also supported)

Answer (score 13):

There are several ways of providing dynamic targets to your Prometheus. Please refer the link [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/)

Some of them are:

- azure_sd_config (for AzureVM metrics)
- consul_sd_config (for Consul's Catalog API)
- dns_sd_config (DNS-based service discovery)
- ec2_sd_config (for AWS EC2 instances)
- openstack_sd_config (for Openstack Nova instances)
- file_sd_config (file-based service discovery)

I think what you require is file_sd_config. `file_sd_config` is a more generic way to configure static targets. You may provide the targets in a yaml or json format. Please follow the [link](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config) for detailed information.